# Math in JavaScript (Numbers)

Tags: javascript, math

I have a table as follows:

```
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+
| 4  | 5  | 6  |
+----+----+----+
| 7  | 8  | 9  |
+----+----+----+
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
+----+----+----+
| 13 | 14 | 15 |
+----+----+----+
| 16 | 17 | 18 |
+----+----+----+
| 19 ....
```

If I choose a random number (for example : 24)
The number 24 will be in C

Is there a way to know where any number will be located?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: Try `num % 3` , returns 1 => A, 2 => B, 0 => C

Comment: Please add the code. How is this data structured? Is it an array of objects? 2D array?

Comment: aswin kumar thanks man

Comment: @brown34 Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think like this code

```js
function get(n) {
  return ['A', 'B', 'C'][(n - 1) % 3];
}

console.log(get(1)); // A
console.log(get(5)); // B
console.log(get(24)); // C
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just converting number to character based on this logic, you can use [`String.fromCharcode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) like this:

```js
const getChar = n => String.fromCharCode((n-1) % 3 + 65)

console.log(getChar(1))
console.log(getChar(2))
console.log(getChar(3))
console.log(getChar(4))
```